# .focus() not working, browser keeps focusing the body

Tags: html, reactjs, focus, accessibility

I am currently working on the accessibility for the React modules at our company.
Although I am just a hobby webdev I would still really like to solve this.

**What's going on is:**

We have a module with 6 steps, after clicking a next button it should hop to the top of the next step after being mounted, this does not seem to work in any kind of way and it keeps focusing the body.

**What I've tried:**

- I have made use of `useRef()` and when I log the referred element it
  works like it should, but when I use `focusRef.current.focus()`
  nothing is happening.
- In `document.activeElement` within the console it shows body as the active element after the new element is mounted.
- `NerdeFocus` (a focus plugin) also shows the body as focussed
- I also tried just selecting the element with `document.getElementById("focusRef")` with no result

**The code of step 1:**

```
export default function Step1(props) {
  const focusRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    focusRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  const {
    reservationItems,
    setStep,
    setSelectedReservation,
    step,
    setAddresses,
    setSelectedAddress,
  } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();

  function onSelectReservation(reservation) {
    setSelectedReservation(reservation);
    setStep(2);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="srOnly">
        Stap 2, kies waar u wilt reserveren
      </Typography>
      <h1 ref={focusRef} className={classes.title}>
        Kies waar u wilt reserveren
      </h1>
      <div className={classes.addressButtons}>
        {reservationItems?.map((reservation, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={i}
              className={classes.addressButton}
              onClick={() => onSelectReservation(reservation)}
            >
              <span>{reservation.Description}</span>
              <span>
                {reservation.Street +
                  ' ' +
                  reservation.Housenumber +
                  ' ' +
                  reservation.City}
              </span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>

      <Button
        className={classes.buttonPrev}
        variant="contained"
        startIcon={<KeyboardArrowLeftIcon />}
        onClick={() => {
          setStep(step - 1);
          setAddresses([]);
          setSelectedAddress([]);
        }}
      >
        Terug
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this issue, thanks in advance Tom.

Comment: have you tried setting an initial value to useRef? ```const focusRef = useRef(null);```

Comment: Yes,  I have tried it with null. Thanks though :)

Comment: You're using `focusRef` on `<h1>` tag. `focusRef.current.focus()` method is used for `<input>` tags.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: What I want is that the screenreaders reads out that users are on the next step and what is possible on that next step = the heading. And a logical content order of course because as it is now it starts at the bottom of the page next to the back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to the React side but in general with single page applications (SPA) when you go to the next step, you want to move the focus to the new heading on the next step.  It sounds like that's what you are attempting to do.

With non-React applications, this works fine.  Perhaps there's a timing issue with React?  Does the element you're trying to move the focus **to** exist in the DOM when you call `focus()`?

In some browsers, you can't move the focus to a non-interactive element **unless** that element has [`tabindex="-1"`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-tabindex-attribute).  I didn't see a `tabindex` in your sample code so perhaps that's the issue.

For example, if I have:

```
<h1 id="myID">Step 2 of the process</h1>
```

and I try to call

```
document.getElementById('myID').focus();
```

some browsers will **not** move the focus to the heading.  But if I change my HTML to:

```
<h1 id="myID" tabindex="-1">Step 2 of the process</h1>
```

then it works.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, everything is working as supposed now. Thanks alot! I was calling the focus() method within useEffect so that is after everything is mounted. Should've thought about tabindex earlier.